# Laravel Price Filter Wherebetween

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have price filter slider on my Laravel project and I am using [Bootstrap slider](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.min.js).

Here is my input code on view

```
<input name="price" id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="2000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]" onchange="checkBoxHandler()"/>
```

Here is my auto submit script on Javascript

```
<script> 
    function checkBoxHandler() { 
        $('#color_form').submit(); 
    } 

    $("#ex2").slider({});
</script>
```

Here is my controller

```
$price = $request->price;
if (request()->has('price')) {
    $products = product::whereBetween('price', [$price])
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags){
            $query->where('name', $tags);
        })->paginate(20);
```

And I got the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where `price` between 250,1400 and swim and exists (select * from `categories` inner join `category_product` on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`category_id` where `products`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id` and `name` = ?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whereBetween, you need to pass array.

```
whereBetween('price', explode(',', $price))
```